# jQuery: How to remove CSS class from both parent and its direct child?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#menu-main > li").add("#menu-main > li > a").removeClass("hover").find("div").hide();

<ul id="menu-main">
   <li class="hover">
     <a class="hover" href="" title="">ABC</a>

     <div>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="" title="">XYZ</a><li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </li>
```

This works but any idea to write this better please or must I repeat "#menu-main > li" for the add() part?

Comment: You can post html code in your post by putting it inside backticks ( ` )

Comment: Why does the title say *"...from both parent and its direct child"*, but the question reads *"...only from the direct anchor children of the li"*?

Comment: Also, you have `"#menu-main > li > a"` right there in your question. Did you try it?

Comment: yeah my bad, i want to remove the hover class from both the li and its first anchor child. The div is a sibling of this anchor.

Comment: For DOM selection/traversal questions, you really need to provide a sample of the DOM you're working with. When you do, you'll have a bunch of perfectly accurate answers within seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#menu-main > li").add("#menu-main > li > a").removeClass("hover")
```

That works, alternatively you can use

```
$("#menu-main > li").children('a').andSelf().removeClass("hover")
```

Comment: I was thinking about the andSelf(). Thanks Thong Kuah!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this

```
$("#menu-main > li > a").removeClass("hover").find("div").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just first item you can use first like:

```
$("#menu-main li a:first").removeClass("hover").find("div").hide();
```